# Defining explicit conversion for custom types in Swift

Tags: swift, type-conversion

What is currently the best/preferred way to define explicit conversions in Swift? Of the top of my head I can think of two:

- Creating custom initializers for the destination type via an extension, like this:

  ```
  extension String {
    init(_ myType: MyType) {
      self = "Some Value"
    }
  }
  ```

  This way, you could just use `String(m)` where m is of type `MyType` to convert m to a string.
- Defining `toType`-Methods in the source type, like this:

  ```
  class MyType {
    func toString() -> String {
      return "Some Value"
    }
  }
  ```

  This is comparable to Swift's `String.toInt()`, which returns an `Int?`. But if this was the definitive way to go I would expect there to be protocols for the basic types for this, like an inversion of the already existing `*LiteralConvertible` protocols.

Sub-question: None of the two methods allow something like this to compile: `let s: MyString = myTypeInstance (as String)` (part in parentheses optional), but if I understand right, the `as` operator is only for downcasting within type hierarchies, is that correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pattern used in swift is the initializer. So for instance when converting an `Int` to `UInt`, we have to write:

```
var i: Int = 10
var u: UInt = UInt(i)
```

I would stick with that pattern.

As for the subquestion, the documentation states that:

> Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance, and/or to treat that instance as if it is a different superclass or subclass from somewhere else in its own class hierarchy.

and

> You can also use type casting to check whether a type conforms to a protocol

so no, the `as` keyword can`t be used to transform a value of a certain type to another type.

That can be tested in a simple way:

```
var i: Int = 10
var u: UInt = i as UInt
```

That generates an error:

```
'Int' is not convertible to 'UInt'
```

More about [Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_498)

Comment: OK, thanks. Also nice of you to include the documentation. I take it that providing extensions for built-in types for conversion is also the right thing to do?

Comment: Yes, extensions is the tool in our hands when we are adding to 3rd party types. For our own code, it's just a matter of preference of course. In some cases using extensions can help keeping our code more organized and easier to browse.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I just need implicit conversion for the few cases where it does make sense, but that I won't get from Swift. ;-)

Comment: @Kolja: Actually you had gotten that in Swift, but they had a range of compiler problems and removed it early on.  It used to be that you could define conversion functions (copy constructors in C++ parlance).  To me, this is a hole in the language - the absence of this blocks a number of techniques.

Comment: Actually this is still implemented somehow for NSNumber, which you can cast to numerous Swift primitives, i.e. `number as? Double` and `number as? Int` both succeed.

Comment: Yup, specially implemented in the runtime:  https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSNumber.swift.gyb

Comment: Agh, so I can't implement a custom cast function (something like C#'s [`implicit operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)) in Swift? That's a shame... the implicit `Error` -> `NSError` bridge used when passing `Error`s to Objective-C code is broken and crashes for background services (at least when in a Framework, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859552/swift-3-custom-urlprotocol-crashes-when-converting-error-to-nserror); calling my own `asNSError()` works but I was hoping to make it automatic.