# Swift 3 custom URLProtocol crashes when converting Error to NSError

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, crash, nserror

I've got a rather large body of Swift 3 code for Mac OS 10.11 and up (using Xcode 8.2.1). There are a number of processes, among them a GUI application and a background service. Both of these use a custom `URLProtocol`, which is implemented in a framework (imported by both application and service). The protocol sometimes may generate instances of an `enum` that conforms to `Error`, which it catches and handles appropriately (generally by using the URLProtocolClient to toss them up to the URLSession trying to make the request).

- When there's no error, both the app and the service work fine.
- When there *is* an error, the app works fine (well, as expected).
- **When there is an error, the service crashes**.

Wandering through the debugger has shown that this crash is occurring when the `Error` is automatically converted into an `NSError` by the runtime. I added this cast explicitly in my code, and sure enough, I get the same crash, now on that line.

I saw [Swift 3.1: Crash when custom error is converted to NSError to access its domain property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225036/swift-3-1-crash-when-custom-error-is-converted-to-nserror-to-access-its-domain), but it doesn't apply here:

- The solution there - extending the `Error` to a `CustomNSError` (and `LocalizedError` for good measure) and implementing the relevant properties - didn't help.
- The crash occurs after the `domain` has been obtained; as far as I can tell that was not a problem for me.
- Possibly relevant: that was on iOS, not Mac.

Having already tried the only listed solution to that question, I'm at something of a loss. I've been debugging this for hours without getting anywhere except that it seems to happen somewhere deep in the guts of `dyld`.

Code:

```
enum CrowbarProtocolError: Error {
    case FailedToCreateSocket;
    case PathTooLong;
    case NonSocketFile;
    case SocketNotFound;
...
    case UnrecognizedError(errno: Int32);
}
extension CrowbarProtocolError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        return "Some localized description"
    }
}
extension CrowbarProtocolError: CustomNSError {
    public static var errorDomain: String {
        return "Some Domain Name"
    }
    public var errorCode: Int {
        return 204 //Should be your custom error code.
    }
    public var errorUserInfo: [String: Any] {
        return ["WTF": "Swift?"];
    }
}
...
open class CrowbarUrlProtocol: URLProtocol  {
...
    override open func startLoading() {
        do {
            let sockHandle = try CrowbarUrlProtocol.openSocket();
            let req = try buildRequestData();
            sockHandle.write(req);
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self, 
                selector: #selector(self.readCompleted), 
                name: .NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletion, 
                object: nil);
            sockHandle.readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify();
        } catch let err {
            Log.warn("CrowbarUrlProtocol request failed with error \(err)");
            // -- In the background service, THIS LINE CRASHES! --
            let err2 = err as NSError;
            Log.warn("As NSError: \(err2)");
            // -- Without the explicit cast, it crashes on this line --
            self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: err);
        }
    }
...
}
```

One idea I have for solving this is just doing everything (or, as much as possible) using `NSError`s, on the grounds that if there's never a need to convert an `Error` to an `NSError`, then whatever is causing this crash won't happen. No idea if it'll work but it seems worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

OK, as far as I can tell this is just a bug in Swift's runtime, but I found a work-around: just use `NSError` for everything involving Obj-C code rather than Swift `Error`s (to avoid the implicit cast). Since I already was implementing `CustomNSError`, it was easy to just create a `toNSError()` function on my `Error` enum, and use that for the `self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: err)` lines.

```
enum CrowbarProtocolError: Error, CustomNSError {
    case FailedToCreateSocket;
    case PathTooLong;
...
    public func asNSError() -> NSError {
        return NSError(domain: CrowbarProtocolError.errorDomain,
                    code: self.errorCode,
                    userInfo: self.errorUserInfo);
    }
}
...
open class CrowbarUrlProtocol: URLProtocol  {
...
    override open func startLoading() {
        do {
            let sockHandle = try CrowbarUrlProtocol.openSocket();
            let req = try buildRequestData();
            sockHandle.write(req);
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self, 
                selector: #selector(self.readCompleted), 
                name: .NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletion, 
                object: nil);
            sockHandle.readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify();
        } catch let err as CrowbarProtocolError {
            Log.warn("CrowbarUrlProtocol request failed with error \(err)");
            self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: err.asNSError());
        }
        catch let err {
            Log.warn("CrowbarUrlProtocol caught non-CrowbarProtocol Error \(err)");
            // This would probably crash the service, but shouldn't ever happen
            self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: err);
        }
    }
...
}
```